# Dockerfile wants to copy shell script to /usr/bin but I'm running Windows

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using Docker with Windows 10.  The Dockerfile for my app includes the following lines:

```
# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY docker/entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
```

The problem is that because the OS is Win 10, there is no `/usr/bin/` path--the equivalent I guess would be `C:\Program Files`.  So when I run `docker-compose up` (in VS Code's Bash terminal), I get the following error:

```
my_app_name   | exec /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
my_app_name exited with code 1
```

Changing the path in the Dockerfile doesn't seem like a good idea, because then Linux users will have the same problem.  What is the right way to handle this for compatibility with both Windows and Linux?

EDIT: the `entrypoint.sh` script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /docker-rails/tmp/pids/server.pid

# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

and the entire Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client cron
RUN mkdir /docker-rails
WORKDIR /docker-rails
COPY Gemfile /docker-rails/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /docker-rails/Gemfile.lock
WORKDIR /docker-rails
RUN bundle install
COPY . /docker-rails
# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY docker/entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000
# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: is this really the only difference? hos is your entrypoint.sh shell script written? is it written in a way that it would work on linux and windows? cause even if you solve the problem of the dir path, I get the feeling this entrypoint.sh is a shell script that wont work on windows. Generally you would have a separate image for windows and linux since they are totally different OS/arch. if you had some common things in the image, you could make a base image then build a windows and linux image. Have a look at https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world for examples of same docker name with OS versions

Comment: Are you creating a windows image? I suppose not. Show the `FROM ...` line of your docker file

Comment: source here, https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world

Comment: The latter path is the destination inside the container. Of course there is a /usr/bin since the container is always Linux.

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent why do you think a container is "*always windows*" ? While it's the default case, there are also windows containers (although you can create and run them only in windows)

Comment: @ChrisDoyle @derpirscher added the `entrypoint.sh` and entirety of Dockerfile to my question

Comment: So your using ruby as the base image, so /usr/bin will exist inside the container. If you want to run this in windows using windows subsytem for linux then this will still work. However if you want to run this in windows as a windows container then you need another docker file that has windows container as the base image

Comment: Your image is based on a Linux image. So inside your container you will always be running a Linux os, so `/usr/bin` is perfectly fine (because it references a path inside the container). You seem to have some basic misunderstandings of docker concepts. Please read some introductions about the basics of images and containers

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I'm thinking about running a Linux VM inside Windows and doing everything inside that VM (installing Docker, building the container, etc).  Do you think that would be a practical way to do this?  It's not important for me to have a Windows container, I'm just running Win 10 on my dev machine

Comment: @derpirscher because OP is obviously using a dockerfile they did not write by themselves

Comment: @sigil no need for all the vm stuff, again, please read some introduction to docker first

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent yes that is correct.  This app was created by someone else, and I am just trying to get it to run on my machine so that I can do some dev work on it.